# Package python software with pylucene dependency

Tags: python, docker, pip, dependencies, pylucene

I'm working on a python project that needs **pylucene**(python wrapper for lucene, a java library for search-engines programming).

I've created a Dockerfile that automatically downloads and compile pylucene; then also installs other needed pip dependencies.
I builded this Dockerfile obtaining a **docker image with all the dependencies**(both pylucene and the others installed using pip).

Setting in pycharm this image as **remote python interpreter** I can run my code, but now I need to release my software in a way that allows to **execute it also without pycharm** or any other IDE that support remote interpreters.

I thought about creating another Dockerfile that starts from the dependency image and then **copy in it my source** obtaining an image where the code can be executed.

I don't like this solution much beacause the objective of my project is processing **large offline datasets**, so in this way the user of this image always have to specify bindings between container and host filesystem.

Are there any better options? Maybe creating an archive that contains my source, pylucene and pip dependencies?

Windows 10 64 bit, python 3.8.2, pylucene latest version (8.3.0)